# Service variable not updating in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

i have a variable workingIdx that needs to be updated to the id the div it is clicked on. It updates but when i query it again, it does not show new value.

My service:

```
writingPage.service('Lctr', function() {

this.workingIdx = 0;
    return {
        getWorkingIdx: this.workingIdx,
        setWorkingIdx: function(i) {
            this.workingIdx = i;
            console.log("wIdx="+this.workingIdx);
        }
    };
});
```

My Controller where i am doing the updating and checking...

```
writingPage.controller('DataController' , ['SnippetPojo','$scope', '$timeout', 'Lctr', function(SnippetPojo, $scope, $timeout, Lctr) {

$scope.currDispLine = '';
$scope.myId = -1;
    $scope.localCursor = 0;

$scope.hideOrShow = function(id, currentDivCursor) {
    if(id <= currentDivCursor)
    {
        console.log("wIdx="+Lctr.getWorkingIdx+ " id="+id);
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }

}

$scope.click = function(id) {
            $scope.myId = id;
            Lctr.setWorkingIdx($scope.myId);
    console.log('MyId='+$scope.myId);
}

$('div').on( "keypress", function( event ) {
    console.log("Event="+event.keyCode + " : "+event.which);
    code = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if ( (code == 37 || code == 39) && event.shiftKey == true) 
    {    
            $timeout(function() {console.log('Selection set= ' +window.getSelection()); return false;}, 2200);

    }
    if ( code == 13) {
                console.log("ENTERed ID="+$scope.myId + " wIdxOLD = "+ Lctr.getWorkingIdx);
        if(Lctr.getWorkingIdx == $scope.myId) {

            Lctr.setWorkingIdx(Number(Lctr.getWorkingIdx) +1);
            localCursor = (Number(Lctr.getWorkingIdx) +1);
            console.log("ENTERed ID="+$scope.myId + " wIdxNEW = "+ Lctr.getWorkingIdx);

            $('#'+$scope.myId).blur();
            $('#'+(Number(Lctr.getWorkingIdx) +1)).mousedown();

            return false;
        }
    }
});
}]);
}
```

Finally the HTML

```
<div id='repeater' data-ng-controller='RepeatController'>
        <!--<data-ng-div-line data-ng-repeat="div in divs track by $index" id="{{$index}}"></data-ng-div-line>-->
        <div data-ng-repeat="div in divs track by $index" id="{{div}}" data-ng-controller='DataController' data-ng-click='click(div)' contenteditable="true" class="writediv" data-ng-model="localCursor" data-ng-mouseover="setId(div)" data-ng-show="!hideOrShow(div, localCursor)" data-ng-hide="hideOrShow(div, localCursor)"></div>
</div>
```

I see wIdx=1 set when i click the DIV and then the ENTERed ID=0 wIdxNEW = 0 displayed when i press enter in the DIV,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try chaging this to self...

```
writingPage.service('Lctr', function() {

var self = this;

self.workingIdx = 0;
    return {
        getWorkingIdx: self.workingIdx,
        setWorkingIdx: function(i) {
            self.workingIdx = i;
            console.log("wIdx="+self.workingIdx);
        }
    };
});
```

`this` gets a new value inside a function

Comment: Hi, tried that but it did not solve the problem. still seeing same values in console.

Comment: Does the service object not behave as a singleton giving same information to each of the controllers?

Comment: it does but `self.workingIdx = 0;` would reset the value whenever you inject, so as good as starting fresh

Comment: Thanks! i tried to convert getWorkingIdx to a function but now the function is getting assigned to the variable and not returning the value of     workingIdx. What am i doing wrong? `getWorkingIdx: function() {
            if(self.workingIdx < 0) self.workingIdx = 0;
            return self.workingIdx;
        },`

Comment: You should also check for undefined

Comment: Thanks! i did it and it worked to return value than function but i'm still facing original problem where wIdxNEW is still same as wIdxOLD. Before printing out wIdxNEW it prints out wIdx changed to 1 and then moves it back to 0. I would have marked your answer as final but for this...

Comment: Found something interesting... `console.log('It Is: ' +self.workingIdx);` i added this line before anything is done in Get method of Service. its printing the first time and for each time get method is called in Controller, it does not print out. To me it looks like the getWorkingIdx is being cached and reused. That intern results in pervious value rather than updated value. Am i correct?

Comment: I think i found my problem... instead of coding getWorkingIdx() i have been coding it as getWorkingIdx without the parentheses...